# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Problem with WIFI repeater/extender

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, 20.04

it seems to be a weird problem with Ubuntu 20.04. My Intel Wireless 7265 does not connect to the WIFI repeater/extender. It does connect to the main router and other wifis. Even my phone hotspot. I tried the live USB, and with Ubuntu 19 works but not with 20.04. So it is a problem in the latest version. One person in Reddit also found the same issue. I tried to re install the network manager and few other things, like other kernels but none work.

```
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 7265
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 61
serial: 4c:34:88:bf:db:78
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:145 memory:a1100000-a1101fff
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: anyone has any tips? This is what I tried so far:

    Different kernels
    re install network manager
    update firmware

The only solution I found is reverting back to the previous version of Ubuntu which is not something I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: Similar problem with 6235 card.

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh you have to modify parameters:

```
init_wpa_cli () {
    [ -n "$WPA_ACTION_SCRIPT" ] || return 0

    local WPA_CLI_OPTIONS
    WPA_CLI_OPTIONS="-p bgscan='simple:30:-70:3600' -B -P $WPA_CLI_PIDFILE -i $WPA_IFACE"
```

bgscan parameter is required. I found that on archlinux forum https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wpa_supplicant#Roaming

Answer (score 1):

In my experience check the following:

1. The password is correct (sounds stupid but it isn't!)
2. The channel is supported by your wifi card. The repeater may be in a Channel your card can't connect to, or will refuse to due to the region (to comply with local laws and regulations)
3. The repeater should be in a different channel as the main AP.
4. The Bandwidth is supported by your wifi card (i.e. 20Mhz vs 40Mhz for 2.4Ghz signals) and both the repeater and the main AP are in the same BW configuration
5. The standard mode (e.g. 802.11 b/g/n) is supported by your wifi card. Try forcing each standard instead of auto.
6. AP isolation is off (in the main AP config)